Ridge Regression in terms of SVD and estimator variance between training and testing sampling
I'm trying to understand more deeply about how Ridge can reduce the variance of model fit due to impefect multicollinearity issue(assume $X$ still full rank but highly correlated.)
As known,
$$Y=X\beta + e$$
$$\hat{\beta} = arg\underset{\beta}min ||Y-X\beta||^2 + \lambda||\beta||^2$$
solution as
$$\hat{\beta} = (X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TY$$
$$\hat{Y}=X(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TY$$
also, we can get estimator variance
$$var(\hat{\beta})=var((X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TY)
\\=var((X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^T(X\beta+e))$$
as $\beta$ is constant
$$var(\hat{\beta})=(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^Tvar(e)X(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}
\\=\sigma^2(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}X^TX(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1}
$$
with SVD as $X=U\Sigma V^T$, we have
$$X^TX=V\Sigma^2 V^T
\\(X^TX+\lambda I)^{-1} = (V\Sigma^2V^T+\lambda I)^{-1} = (V\Sigma^2V^T+V\lambda I V^T)^{-1} = V(\Sigma^2+\lambda I)^{-1}V^T
$$
Then
$$var(\hat{\beta})=\sigma^2V(\Sigma^2+\lambda I)^{-1}V^T V \Sigma^2 V^T V(\Sigma^2+\lambda I)^{-1}V^T
\\=\sigma^2V(\Sigma^2+\lambda I)^{-1}\Sigma^2(\Sigma^2+\lambda I)^{-1}V^T
\\var(\hat{Y})=Xvar(\hat{\beta})X^T=\sigma^2U\Sigma(\Sigma^2+\lambda I)^{-1}\Sigma^2(\Sigma^2+\lambda I)^{-1}\Sigma^T U^T
$$
We also know
$$\hat{\beta}=V(\Sigma^2+\lambda I)^{-1}V^T V\Sigma U^T Y
\\=V(\Sigma^2+\lambda I)^{-1}\Sigma U^T Y
$$
so we know $\hat{\beta}$ is being penaltized through $\lambda$ which penalize eigenvalue when it's relative small compare to other eigenvalues.
Also ref. from Variance of ridge regression estimator $var(\hat{\beta})$ got decreased due to penalty
My questions are

As penalization has the most effect on small eigenvalue. Does small eigenvalue cause the traing sampling and testing sampling performance divergence? Why is that?

How to quantify the variance of prediction power between training and testing sampling? Then how to interpret such penalization effect on the variance?


Much appreciated if anyone can explain in a rigourous and mathematical way.
